# Create Tuples out of JSON File

Tags: python, json, postgresql, parsing, formatting

I've been working on parsing a JSON file to make it easier to work with in PostgreSQL and was wondering what the best method would be to parse a JSON dictionary into tuples?

For example the lines look like this for the two variables:

The first

```
"attributes": {"RestaurantsTableService": false, "GoodForMeal": {"dessert": false, "latenight": false, "lunch": false, "dinner": false, "breakfast": false, "brunch": false}, "Alcohol": "none", "Caters": true, "HasTV": false, "RestaurantsGoodForGroups": true, "NoiseLevel": "quiet", "WiFi": "no", "RestaurantsAttire": "casual", "RestaurantsReservations": false, "OutdoorSeating": false, "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": true, "RestaurantsPriceRange2": 1, "BikeParking": true, "RestaurantsDelivery": false, "Ambience": {"romantic": false, "intimate": false, "classy": false, "hipster": false, "divey": false, "touristy": false, "trendy": false, "upscale": false, "casual": false}, "RestaurantsTakeOut": true, "GoodForKids": true, "BusinessParking": {"garage": false, "street": false, "validated": false, "lot": false, "valet": false}}
```

The second:

```
"hours": {"Monday": "7:30-22:00", "Tuesday": "7:30-22:00", "Friday": "7:30-22:00", "Wednesday": "7:30-22:00", "Thursday": "7:30-22:00", "Sunday": "7:30-21:00", "Saturday": "7:30-22:00"}
```

I want them to be in this format:

For attributes:

```
Attributes: [(RestaurantsTableService, False)(dessert, False)(latenight, False)(lunch, False)(dinner, False)(breakfast, False)(brunch, False)(Alcohol, none)(Caters, True)(HasTV, False)(RestaurantsGoodForGroups, True)(NoiseLevel, quiet)(WiFi, no)(RestaurantsAttire, casual)(RestaurantsReservations, False)(OutdoorSeating, False)(BusinessAcceptsCreditCards, True)(RestaurantsPriceRange2, 1)(BikeParking, True)(RestaurantsDelivery, False)(romantic, False)(intimate, False)(classy, False)(hipster, False)(divey, False)(touristy, False)(trendy, False)(upscale, False)(casual, False)(RestaurantsTakeOut, True)(GoodForKids, True)(garage, False)(street, False)(validated, False)(lot, False)(valet, False)]
```

For Hours:

```
Hours: [(Friday, 9:00,12:00)(Tuesday, 14:00,19:00)(Thursday, 14:00,19:00)(Wednesday, 14:30,17:00)(Monday, 14:30,17:00)]
```

Here is my code so far. For now I've been trying to access the values for each of the dictionaries in the variables. I was able to iterate through them but have been unable to access the boolean, integer or string values.

```
import json
import ast
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict

def cleanStr4SQL(s):
    return s.replace("'","`").replace("\n"," ")


def parseBusinessData():
    #read the JSON file
    with open('yelp_business.JSON','r') as f:  #Assumes that the data files are available in the current director. If not, you should set the path for the yelp data files.  
        outfile =  open('business.txt', 'w')
        line = f.readline()
        count_line = 0
        #read each JSON abject and extract data
        while line:
            data = json.loads(line)


#            jsondict = ast.literal_eval(str(data))
#            df = pd.DataFrame(jsondict['attributes'])
#            df['features'] = df.index.str.rjust(5, '0')
#            df['atts'] = df['features'].apply(attributes)
#            outfile.write(str([item for item in df['atts']]) + '\t')
#            df = df.apply(attributes)
#            print(str([item for item in data['attributes']]))
            outfile.write(str([k for k in [item for item in [l for l in data['attributes']]]]) + '\t') # write your own code to process attributes
            outfile.write(str([item for item in data['hours']]) + '\t') # write your own code to process hours
            outfile.write('\n');

            line = f.readline()
            count_line +=1
    print(count_line)
    outfile.close()
    f.close()

def attributes(val):
    if val == False:
        return 0
    if val == True:
        return 1
```

Please let me know if you have any further questions or concerns. Any advice is appreciated.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: When dealing with dictionaries, you are implicitly accessing the keys when you iterate over the dict, the same as doing `dict.keys()`. You might try `dict.values()` for just the values or dict.`iteritems()` for the key value pairs.

Comment: In your first JSON, there's something like `GoodForMeal: {dessert:false}`, which doesn't appear in your expected result. Is that intentional?

Comment: No my apologies it is not intentional. I made these examples up on the spot to mainly give an example of how I want to reformat the data. I apologize for any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question, it looks like you want to generate a string in a particular format, flattening the attributes in the nested dictionaries.

Is this what you want?

```
import json

def flatten(D,key):
    L = []
    for k,v in D[key].items():
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            for kk,vv in v.items():
                L.append((kk,vv))
        else:
            L.append((k,v))
    return L

att_json = '{"attributes": {"RestaurantsTableService": false, "GoodForMeal": {"dessert": false, "latenight": false, "lunch": false, "dinner": false, "breakfast": false, "brunch": false}, "Alcohol": "none", "Caters": true, "HasTV": false, "RestaurantsGoodForGroups": true, "NoiseLevel": "quiet", "WiFi": "no", "RestaurantsAttire": "casual", "RestaurantsReservations": false, "OutdoorSeating": false, "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards": true, "RestaurantsPriceRange2": 1, "BikeParking": true, "RestaurantsDelivery": false, "Ambience": {"romantic": false, "intimate": false, "classy": false, "hipster": false, "divey": false, "touristy": false, "trendy": false, "upscale": false, "casual": false}, "RestaurantsTakeOut": true, "GoodForKids": true, "BusinessParking": {"garage": false, "street": false, "validated": false, "lot": false, "valet": false}}}'
att = json.loads(att_json)
att_list = flatten(att,'attributes')
s = 'Attributes: [' + ''.join(['({}, {})'.format(k,v) for k,v in att_list]) + ']'
print(s)

hours_json = '{"hours": {"Monday": "7:30-22:00", "Tuesday": "7:30-22:00", "Friday": "7:30-22:00", "Wednesday": "7:30-22:00", "Thursday": "7:30-22:00", "Sunday": "7:30-21:00", "Saturday": "7:30-22:00"}}'
hours = json.loads(hours_json)
hours_list = flatten(hours,'hours')
s = 'Hours: [' + ''.join(['({}, {})'.format(k,v.replace('-',',')) for k,v in hours_list]) + ']'
print(s)
```

Output:

```
Attributes: [(RestaurantsTableService, False)(dessert, False)(latenight, False)(lunch, False)(dinner, False)(breakfast, False)(brunch, False)(Alcohol, none)(Caters, True)(HasTV, False)(RestaurantsGoodForGroups, True)(NoiseLevel, quiet)(WiFi, no)(RestaurantsAttire, casual)(RestaurantsReservations, False)(OutdoorSeating, False)(BusinessAcceptsCreditCards, True)(RestaurantsPriceRange2, 1)(BikeParking, True)(RestaurantsDelivery, False)(romantic, False)(intimate, False)(classy, False)(hipster, False)(divey, False)(touristy, False)(trendy, False)(upscale, False)(casual, False)(RestaurantsTakeOut, True)(GoodForKids, True)(garage, False)(street, False)(validated, False)(lot, False)(valet, False)]
Hours: [(Monday, 7:30,22:00)(Tuesday, 7:30,22:00)(Friday, 7:30,22:00)(Wednesday, 7:30,22:00)(Thursday, 7:30,22:00)(Sunday, 7:30,21:00)(Saturday, 7:30,22:00)]
```

Comment: Amazingly brilliant! It worked beautifully. Thank you for your help! One quick question though, could you please explain to me how you came up with the flatten function?

Comment: @mrsquid There were only two levels of nested dictionary.  The first for iterates over the top level, and if the value of the key is a dictionary, it iterates over the keys/values of that dictionary.  It basically drops the key name of each nested dictionary and appends the keys/values of the nested dictionary into the same list as the higher level keys/values.

Comment: Ahh I see that makes sense! Thank you for the explanation!